# JconfirmAction and ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have problem to compare JconfirmAction with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".delbutton").click(function () {
        //Save the link in a variable called element
        var element = $(this);
        //Find the id of the link that was clicked
        var del_id = element.attr("id");

        //Built a url to send
        var info = 'id=' + del_id;
        if (confirm("Sure you want to delete this update? There is NO undo!")) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "ajax_delete.php",
                data: info,
                success: function () {

                }
            });
            $(this).parents(".record").animate({
                backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7"
            }, "fast")
                .animate({
                opacity: "hide"
            }, "slow");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

I try to add this script to exist page with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.ask-custom').jConfirmAction({question : "Usunąć ?", yesAnswer : "Tak", cancelAnswer : "Nie"});
    });
</script>
```

link with `class`:

```
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" title="DELETE" class="ask-custom delbutton">
```

any hints?
best regards.

Comment: So... what's the error?

Comment: there is no error, just i dont know how to compare this two script. i try to change 'if (confirm..' to jConfirmAction but I'm doing something wrong :(

Comment: Those might be two different libraries with two different stories

Comment: nope. i wonder how to change 'if confirm' to '$('.ask-custom').jConfirmAction'

Answer (score 0):

Try change your `ajax` request:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "ajax_delete.php",
                data: {id:del_id},
                success: function () {

                }
            });
```

Comment: nothing. still when i click confirm "YES" nothing was changed.